# How to get value of an XML node if another node sharing the same parent equals a certain value?

Tags: c#, xml, database

My XML is structured like this:

```
<Database>
  <Member>
    <Name>PersonA</Name>
    <Rank>RankIWant</Rank>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <Name>PersonB</Name>
    <Rank>RankIDontWant</Rank>
  </Member>
</Database>
```

I have the `<Name>` value of PersonA, and I want "RankIWant", but I'm not sure how to get it with the information that I have. What do I do?

Comment: Find the Name node with the value you want, get the parent, read value of Rank. See XDocument. Can also be done with a single XPath statement but baby steps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`XPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) query. For your example:

```xml
//Member[Name = "PersonA"]/Rank
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/udobyd

That `XPath` query means, select all (the `//` means all, independent of the position) `Rank` nodes who have a parent `Member` node which happens to have a `Name` descendant with the value `PersonA`.

You could also use Linq to Xml if you are used to Linq. In this case, the equivalent code would be:

```
var nodes = XElement.Parse(xml).Descendants("Rank")
        .Where(x => x.Parent.Descendants("Name").Any(y => y.Value == "PersonA"));
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bOVOy7

For your specific query, I'd prefer the XPath version, but your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<Database>" +
                  "<Member>" +
                    "<Name>PersonA</Name>" +
                    "<Rank>RankIWant</Rank>" +
                  "</Member>" +
                  "<Member>" +
                    "<Name>PersonB</Name>" +
                    "<Rank>RankIDontWant</Rank>" +
                  "</Member>" +
                "</Database>";

            XElement database = XElement.Parse(xml);

            XElement query = database.Elements("Member")
                .Where(x => x.Element("Rank").Value == "RankIWant").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would need you to know that `Rank` is `RankIWant`. That's not what is stated in the question

Comment: Then search for element Name instead of element Rank.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        string myRankValue = "";

        var xml = @"<Database>
                  <Member>
                    <Name>PersonA</Name>
                    <Rank>RankIWant</Rank>
                  </Member>
                  <Member>
                    <Name>PersonB</Name>
                    <Rank>RankIDontWant</Rank>
                  </Member>
                </Database>";
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var firstMember =
            xDoc.Descendants("Member")
                .Where(d => d.Descendants("Name").First().Value == "PersonA")
                .Descendants("Rank")
                .FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstMember != null)
        {
            myRankValue = firstMember.Value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(myRankValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only give you the value of the first member/rank, it's not querying at all